# How to route in Laravel DataTables

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I am new to Laravel DataTables and i am trying to insert my controller in the datatables but i am getting an exception.

How to get this done?

PS: When I use the normal route like `user/items/'$users->id'/control`, it works fine but I want to use the the route like `UserController@edit, $user->id`

```
public function getPost()
{
    $users= User::where('id', Auth::user()->id);
    return Datatables::of($users)->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
        return '<a href="{ action('UserController@edit', $user->id)}" title="edit" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;';

    })->make(true);     

}
```

Comment: what datatable? where's your datatable?

Comment: @dexterb, i don't think i need to post my datatable here. I want to know if it is possible to do what i am asking in the question

Comment: you should specify what datatable package you are using.

Comment: @dexterb i am using Yajra package

Comment: try like this

return '<a href="'.action('UserController@edit', ['id' => $user->id]).'" title="edit" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';

Comment: Just use Eloquent ORM to make it more readable. Build relations between models: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: reffere here

https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/add-edit-remove-column#edit-4
<br>
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls

Comment: @Shibon, thank you. That worked

Comment: Why do you want to use like UserController@edit? You can directly specify the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mentions to your code:

```
// this will get you only one user
$users = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id);

// therefore it does not make sense to show one user in a table, does it ;-)
return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
```

To your question:

You need two actions: One to render the view and one to fetch the data for the datatables via Ajax (if you use ServerSide rendering)

Assuming you want to show a list of users:

### Routes

```
Route::get('users', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('users-dt', 'UserController@indexDataTables')->name('users:dt');
```

### Controller

```
public function index()
{
    return view('users.index');
}

public function indexDataTables()
{
    $users = User::query();

    return DataTables::eloquent($users)->toJson();
}
```

### user/index.blade.php

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('users:dt') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            ],
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually forgot to specify the parameter name on the second argument of action helper.

```
action('UserController@edit', ['user' => $user->id]);

// Assuming that UserController@edit looks like this:

public function edit(User $user) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
href="'.action('UserController@edit', $user->id).'"
```

Just remove curly braces. with ('..')